# How can I parse the microcode (ucode) in iwlwifi to get the version numbers?

Tags: linux, kernel, intel, firmware, iwlwifi

I have an Intel wireless card driven by `iwlwifi`, and I can see the following message in dmesg:

```
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.168.5.3 build 42301
```

Given that I know which blob is loaded, how I can find out the version of this blob (`.ucode` file)?

If you look at the below where the ucode is loaded, it doesn't tell me the version information just that a blob was loaded. But I know Intel versions these.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep ucode
[   26.132487] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
[40428.475015] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
```

Comment: I suspect it may not load a firmware every time the system boots up, but only reports what firmware version is running on the ethernet card.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `iwlwifi` driver loads the microcode file for your *wifi* adapter at startup. If you want to know the version of the blobs you have on your machine, try [Andrew Brampton's script](https://gist.github.com/bramp/1285857). Run:

```
## Note the firmware may stored in `/usr/lib`
./ucode.py /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-*.ucode
```

And compare the output to your journal (`dmesg` output).

Note that the script works with `python2`.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, and looking at the Andrew Brampton script mentioned in [@don_crissti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46208/3285), you can get the same output from [Radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) which is a reverse-engineering framework.

```
pf x[4]z[64]zN1N1N1N1 magicfile magicblob text serial api minor major
```

- `pf` print formatted data

  - `x` `0xHEX value and flag (fd @ addr) (see 'd' and 'i')`
  - `[4]z` `null terminated string` of min-length 4 size
  - `[64]z` `null terminated string` of min-length 64 size
  - `N1N1N1N1` `next char specifies size of unsigned value (1, 2, 4 or 8 byte(s))`

You can run that from a script like this,

```
for f in /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-*.ucode; do
    echo $f;
    radare2 -qc "pf x[4]z[64]zN1N1N1N1 magicfile magicblob text serial api minor major" "$f";
done;
```

Here is some example output

```
 magicfile : 0x00000000 = 0x00000000
 magicblob : 0x00000004 = IWL.
      text : 0x00000008 = 6000g2b fw v18.168.6.1 build 0.
    serial : 0x00000048 = 1
       api : 0x00000049 = 6
     minor : 0x0000004a = 168
     major : 0x0000004b = 18
```

You play them backwards, `major.minor.api.serial` to get `18.168.6.1`