# Can't connect to a network, getting 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

Validated the network works fine with cell phone and another computer.

Using Lenovo with "Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]". Not sure where to go with this. Any ideas?

Yes, the wifi card in the laptop works on every other network I need to connect to.

The router is running LEDE. The radio running the Access Point is on Channel: 11 (2.462 GHz). The problems only occur when encryption is turned on. I think the problem is with `wpa_supplicant`. I connect to a ton of Access Points with WPA2 just fine. This specific access point is not working. It doesn't take my very simple password. Using `nm-applet` I can see the password in plain text. It's clearly right.

## Logs of problems

### Kernel log

```
[   21.304460] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.311387] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.311489] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   21.595334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.602275] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.602374] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   21.690105] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   24.893663] wlp3s0: authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
[   24.898592] wlp3s0: send auth to 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   24.901900] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   24.905380] wlp3s0: associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   24.909189] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   24.928312] wlp3s0: associated
[   24.928359] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   28.016926] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   31.243868] wlp3s0: authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
[   31.247566] wlp3s0: send auth to 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   31.251159] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   31.256392] wlp3s0: associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   31.260004] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   31.284002] wlp3s0: associated
[   34.365770] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   37.592904] wlp3s0: authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
[   37.595965] wlp3s0: send auth to 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   37.599821] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   37.603457] wlp3s0: associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   37.607156] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   37.626600] wlp3s0: associated
[   40.714220] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   43.941785] wlp3s0: authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
[   43.945306] wlp3s0: send auth to 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   43.948990] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   43.950510] wlp3s0: associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (try 1/3)
[   43.954192] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   43.973663] wlp3s0: associated
[   46.964852] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   60.846793] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
```

### Router (LEDE)

From the AP side with LEDE, I see this,

```
Fri Aug 11 02:57:13 2017 daemon.info hostapd: wlan1: STA 08:11:96:3f:05:5c IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Fri Aug 11 02:57:13 2017 daemon.info hostapd: wlan1: STA 08:11:96:3f:05:5c IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Fri Aug 11 02:57:21 2017 daemon.info hostapd: wlan1: STA 08:11:96:3f:05:5c IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
```

### wpa_supplicant 2.4 STOCK (Ubuntu 16.10)

From `wpa_cli`, I'm getting, this

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE-AUTH 
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Associated with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 reason=2
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

That goes on a bunch and then it ends with

```
<3>WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="EvanCarroll" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=WRONG_KEY
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="EvanCarroll" auth_failures=3 duration=30 reason=CONN_FAILED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

### wpa_supplicant 2.6

Built a new version of wpa_supplicant just to test. No change.

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2432 MHz)
wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2432 MHz)
wlp3s0: Associated with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 reason=2
wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2432 MHz)
wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61 (SSID='EvanCarroll' freq=2432 MHz)
wlp3s0: Associated with 08:02:8e:9b:b1:61
```

## External links

Most of these are just for my own purpose of things that it may be related too

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=146418 I am also connecting to an N router.

Comment: someone want to critique the question? I can't connect to the network, that's in the logs. What more do you want to know? Getting it 4 seconds after association.

Comment: Has it ever worked? What band is your wifi running on?

Comment: @Jesse_b updated with that information.

Comment: My guess is some driver bug that messes up the "authenticated" state. I had spurious deauthentications some time ago (though they looked differently, so it's probably not the same problem as yours), and they went away when I updated the kernel driver. (And no, I have no idea why people downvote valid questions. The question looks completely fine to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure this solved it, but it may be worth trying to upgrade your bios. I have since done that it seems to work now. This also fixed a weird issue where I believe the wifi card would stop the system from suspending.

As a side note, something I didn't know at the time I made this post is that intel versions the firmware blob the kernel runs. You may want to make sure that's the relatively new.. [Finding out the version of the blob can be a non-minor task](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43462/3285)

Comment: As I understand, you claim the problem is in your laptop. It is also possible that the problem may be with your router. I had made an access point from my Linux PC, and it seems the problem was with that.